# How to alternate between two images when a button is clicked, and then stop when it's clicked again, Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, actionlistener

So, I have three classes that I am using to represent a program that is suppose to alternate between an on lightbulb image and an off lightbulb image when the on button is clicked, then switch to the off button image when it's clicked again. Initially, when the program starts, it's default is set to ON, but it stays as the ON image and doesn't alternate, when you clcik the button twice, the program just freezes (I guess it creates an infinite loop). Here is the code I used to handle the Button listener (it's a nested class inside the class I used to create the buttons and add them to the panel) :

```
private class OnListener implements ActionListener
{
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Turns the bulb on and repaints the bulb panel.
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
    {
        if (bulb.isOn()){
            bulb.setOn (false);
            bulb.repaint();
            onButton.setText("Off");
            onButton.setMnemonic ('O');
            add (onButton);
        }
        else{
            bulb.setOn (true);
            onButton.setText("On");
            onButton.setMnemonic ('n');
            add(onButton);

            while (bulb.isOn()){
                bulb.repaint();
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e){
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `JToggleButton` with appropriate icons for default and selected look.

Comment: `Thread.sleep(1000);` Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got both a `while (true)` loop and a `Thread.sleep` statement and both will tie up and the Swing event thread, freezing your GUI, a common problem and common question on this and other similar sites.

The solution:  use a javax.swing.Timer also known as a Swing Timer. In the Timer swap a JLabel's ImageIcon via JLabel's `setIcon(icon)` method.

e.g.,

```
  int delay = 1000;
  final Timer timer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {

     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO put in code to repeat
        // including swapping a JLabel's image icon
     }
  });
  JButton btn = new JButton("Foo");
  btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        timer.start(); // or stop if you want to stop the swapping
     }
  });
```